# How to redirect output string of script src file to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, src

I have looked for a couple of hours for what seemed like an easy question and have tried several things I've found here and elsewhere, but cannot answer this. I run a radio station and the servers outputs the name of the current song in a short script. The script is

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.voscast.com/stats/display.js?key=33d86e1438d74956b30a556c434a952e&stats=songtitle"></script>
```

and works fine. What I want is something that is the equivalent of the Linux > or >> operator so I can store the data that gets put to my screen into a variable instead, so I can use it elsewhere. Sorry if this is so basic, but I've tried a number of different things and just need some specific simple code to fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this using jQuery. It is a complete solution to your question.

```
<html>
<head>

  <!-- This includes the jQuery library you need to extract the song name -->
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>

  <!-- This is the script you want the song name from -->  
  <script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.voscast.com/stats/display.js?key=33d86e1438d74956b30a556c434a952e&stats=songtitle"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('div').filter(function() {
            return /^.{13}/.test(this.id);
        }).each(function() {

            $(this).hide(); // Hide the song name here

            // Assign the name to a variable as you requested
            var songName = this.innerHTML;

            // Just for a demonstration
            alert( songName );

            // Do what you like with the song name here ...
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When the JavaScript file loads, it prints a div and populates it with the name of a song. The div id looks to be a randomly generated 13-character string. You can access that div using a jQuery selection filter - the `/^.{13}/.test(this.id)` part.

Comment: OK, I basically see that, but am not familiar with JSFiddle. Where is the src link supposed to go? I'm clearly missing something here.

Comment: Hi Bob, JSFiddle is just a quick environment to test JS code snippets. I use it to demonstrate my solutions. Now, where do you want the song info to be sent? You mentioned in "a variable".

Comment: I'm trying to make the connection between the "http://cdn.voscast.com/stats/display.js?key=33d86e1438d74956b30a556c434a952e&stats=songtitle" and what you have described. Is that what this - /^.{13}/ - is supposed to represent?

Comment: Yes. The voscast script is on the same page and using jQuery you can access the song name after the script has been processed. I may need to guide you some more on the whole process. Please look at the source of the JSFiddle frames for the time being.

Comment: Thank you Drakes ... It clearly works when I download it, but I clearly was "asleep in class" one day. I am not seeing the connection to  return /^.{13}/.test(this.id);  - specifically the /^.{13}/ part.

Comment: Ah, yes, you see in the script you want the song from it writes a div? It changes each time you load that script. However, it looks to stay at 13 chars in length each time. My solution keys onto that fact. I've updated my answer to include this explanation.

Comment: Ah, I get it!! It's not "returning" a value at all, it's dumping in a dummy div inside the existing space I've allocated for it! I guess I sorta knew that, but was thinking more in terms of grabbing it from the incoming stream like I mentioned a Unix > or >>, than from an existing element. And as a side byproduct, you answered  a question I didn't know I had yet -- how to NOT show the output at all. So you check the current div id and pull the innerHtml from that! Cool! Thanks. Need to read up more on jQuery filters

Comment: Glad this helped you. :) Kindly upvote and accept the answer. You can ask another question about parsing the script file outside of an HTML page if you like.